# Subclass constexpr class to obtain different user-defined conversion behavior

Tags: c++, inheritance, constexpr

I have the following constexpr class from a library, used to create and managed a fixed-point representation of a floating-point number:

```
template< unsigned Integer, unsigned Fraction >
class UFixed : FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::UFixedBase< Integer, Fraction >
{
public:
    static_assert((Integer + Fraction) <= FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::BitSize<uintmax_t>::Value, "Platform does not have a native type large enough for UFixed.");

public:
    using IntegerType = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::LeastUInt<Integer>;
    using FractionType = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::LeastUInt<Fraction>;
    using InternalType = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::LeastUInt<Integer + Fraction>;

    using ShiftType = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::LeastUInt<Integer + Fraction>;
    using MaskType = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::LeastUInt<Integer + Fraction>;

    constexpr const static uintmax_t IntegerSize = Integer;
    constexpr const static uintmax_t FractionSize = Fraction;
    constexpr const static uintmax_t LogicalSize = IntegerSize + FractionSize;
    constexpr const static uintmax_t InternalSize = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::BitSize<InternalType>::Value;

    constexpr const static uintmax_t Scale = 1ULL << FractionSize;

public:
    constexpr const static ShiftType IntegerShift = FractionSize;
    constexpr const static ShiftType FractionShift = 0;

    constexpr const static MaskType IntegerMask = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::IdentityMask<IntegerSize>::Value;
    constexpr const static MaskType FractionMask = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::IdentityMask<FractionSize>::Value;

    constexpr const static MaskType IdentityMask = (IntegerMask << IntegerShift) | (FractionMask << FractionShift);

    constexpr const static MaskType MidpointMask = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::MsbMask<FractionSize>::Value;
    constexpr const static MaskType LesserMidpointMask = MidpointMask - 1;

private:
    using Base = FIXED_POINTS_DETAILS::UFixedBase<Integer, Fraction>;
    using RawType = typename Base::RawType;

public:
    using Base::Base;

    constexpr UFixed(void);
    constexpr UFixed(const IntegerType & integer);
    constexpr UFixed(const IntegerType & integer, const FractionType & fraction);

    constexpr InternalType getInternal(void) const;
    constexpr IntegerType getInteger(void) const;
    constexpr FractionType getFraction(void) const;

    constexpr explicit operator IntegerType(void) const;
    constexpr explicit operator float(void) const;
    constexpr explicit operator double(void) const;

    template< unsigned IntegerOut, unsigned FractionOut >
    constexpr explicit operator UFixed<IntegerOut, FractionOut>(void) const;

    constexpr static UFixed fromInternal(const InternalType & value);

    UFixed & operator ++(void);
    UFixed & operator --(void);
    UFixed & operator +=(const UFixed & other);
    UFixed & operator -=(const UFixed & other);
    UFixed & operator *=(const UFixed & other);
    UFixed & operator /=(const UFixed & other);

public:
    constexpr const static UFixed Epsilon = UFixed::fromInternal(1);
    constexpr const static UFixed MinValue = UFixed::fromInternal(0);
    constexpr const static UFixed MaxValue = UFixed::fromInternal(~0);

    // 40 digits is probably enough for these
    constexpr const static UFixed Pi = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971;
    constexpr const static UFixed E = 2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757;
    constexpr const static UFixed Phi = 1.6180339887498948482045868343656381177203;
    constexpr const static UFixed Tau = 6.2831853071795864769252867665590057683943;
};
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to use inheritance to define a subclass of `UFixed` which behaves materially equivalently, except the user-defined conversion operators for `IntegerType`, `float`, and `double` in the second-to-last block can be applied implicitly, rather than as `explicit`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why you couldn't. What did you try, and how did it break?

Comment: @Quentin e.g. if I attempt to do "double foo = bar;" where bar is of type say  UFixed<8, 8>; I get a "no known conversion" error. "double foo = static_cast<double>(bar);" works OK.

The underlying issue is that the lib is a drop-in replacement for some code I have which uses doubles to store small real numbers, except to make it work I must cast all the assignments throughout the code. I understand the limits of the representation and while that's nice from a safety perspective I'd prefer not to do that at this time ;)

Comment: It's actually more the requirement for casting conversions to integer types, and passing to functions which is the problem. The fundamental type is typedefed so it could be float, double, or any other representation for assignment and logic purposes, but it needs to be able to be passed to several functions which only accept "double." same issue with having to cast explicitly everywhere that happens

Comment: I'm all clear on the end result you want to get, and I agree that subclassing and using your subclass looks like the way to go. But where are you stuck doing that exactly?

Comment: @Quentin Not sure what the subclass should look like with respect to how to get the behavior I want in C++11. Do I need to re-implement all the methods defined there in the parent class just to change those conversions? Little lost on where to begin, subclassing non-virtual/abstract parent classes to change operator behavior like this isn't my strong point...

Comment: Public inheritance will bring all of the stuff from `UFixed` into your derived class' scope. Then you just have to hide the explicit conversion operators from `UFixed` with your implicit ones, which each delegate to their hidden version. `virtual` functions are only useful if the code that uses `UFixed&` (or similar) does not know that the object is actually of another type at runtime, but if the using code is yours you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for my requirements and is also a "constexpr" class as the base class:

```
template <unsigned Integer, unsigned Fraction>
struct MyUFixed : UFixed<Integer, Fraction>
{
   typedef UFixed<Integer, Fraction> fixed_point_t;
   using fixed_point_t::fixed_point_t; //pull in base constructors
   using typename fixed_point_t::IntegerType; //pull in "IntegerType"

   using fixed_point_t::operator double;
   using fixed_point_t::operator float;
   using fixed_point_t::operator IntegerType;

   constexpr MyUFixed(const fixed_point_t& other) :
   fixed_point_t(other) //constructor from base type
   {}

   //implicit conversions

   constexpr operator float() const
   {
      return static_cast<float>(*this);
   }

   constexpr operator double() const
   {
      return static_cast<double>(*this);
   }

   constexpr operator IntegerType() const
   {
      return static_cast<IntegerType>(*this);
   }
};
```